# How to combine categories into a title?

Tags: categorization, tagging, natural-language

*This question is about how categories are displayed, not how they are processed.*

Consider I have a category page that is broken down into blocks of sub categories. The titles of these sub-sections should be based on the combination of two subcategories. For the sake of this example:

Cristiano Ronaldo (category page):

- Section 1: Goals + Arsenal
- Section 2: Goals + Header
- Section 3: Goals + Kicks

(the main category and the lower combinations can be totally arbitrary and doesn't matter at this point)

Ideally, the system should be able to create titles for those sections based on these categories, such as:

- Section 1: Goals against Arsenal
- Section 2: Header Goals
- Section 3: Kicks to Goal

Given the system CANNOT accomplish that at the moment, what would you consider the best / more human way to display these titles?

Example:

- Section 1: Goals and Arsenal
- Section 2: Goals and Header
- Section 3: Goals and Kicks

(a similar approach was tested with some users and were considered confusing)

Thanks!

Comment: Could you share with us the interface tested and a summary of the results?

Comment: Unfortunately not, @NicolasHung. Picture Netflix, in which you get into the rabbit-hole of categories - you go into "Series > Drama" then you might see things like "Drama based on history", "British Drama", etc. I understand these might be curated, but in my case what I'm wondering is whether there's an alternative to curation if the system can't accomplish that natural language approach. Does it make sense?

Comment: What was the response from testing "Goals + Arsenal" format? 
Something like "+" seems to be ambiguous enough for people to make an interpretation. Using a word adds confusion, it instantly generates a phrase tied to a meaning. If the meaning doesn't make sense, it will be confusing. For example, "Goals and Arsenal", "Goals in Arsenal", "Goals with Arsenal" all mean different specific things. Even if the titles could be generated with NLP, the meaning has to match the content you serve them. E.g. "Goals against Arsenal" needs to show goals against Arsenal, any other video would be confusing.

Comment: @NicolasHung your comment makes sense indeed. Sorry, I forgot to mention that the approach tested was the "and", which caused confusion due to the points you raised. Another approach I might test is having just the category in these titles, without combinations, assuming users will imply the hierarchy based on other elements on the page (e.g. main title, state of the navigation, etc.).

Comment: Hey, it seems like your question is two part: (1) Section title wording structure and (2) Section title design. For structure, I do think the “+” is enough, and for design, as long as the titles look like section titles, they should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could treat them as combination of tags. For example, Pinterest treat search terms as tags and suggest new ones to add to the search bar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is an option and we're using that in the search itself, but the question is more like if you broke the results down into multiple category combinations, these sections would have titles, and how would those titles be?